# Haskell mutable Heap structure

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, heap, mutable

I want to make my heap data structure. Also i want to make operations with it in STM monad in multi-threaded application. The heap  have size of 10 millions of elements. There are many operations on heap.

I have looked on this packages

1. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/heap
2. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/heaps

As i mean both of them are persistent. If we modify this data structure we get two versions. 
It is memory ineffective for heap with big size.

As i guess i need to implement mutable heap.

I want to hear your opinion and advice to get what i want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ankur points out, you may be outside the bounds of the pure functional side of Haskell.  At least I have never seen a pure extract-min data structure with good memory performance -- don't take that to mean there isn't one.  Have you profiled the existing libraries to make sure that they are not adequate for your needs?   (Remember that a persistent data structure does *not* mean that the entire data structure is copied whenever a mutation is made, there can be *lots* of sharing between different "versions").

However, Haskell also has an imperative side, and you could implement a heap on that side.  The performance characteristics of imperative Haskell are close to those of any other imperative language, so you will probably want to base your heap off of a mutable array of some type.

It might be tricky to implement it in a way that works nicely with STM, whose core concept is the TVar.  You could base it off of a (even non-mutable) array of TVars, but since every operation touches the root of the heap there will be lots of contention and the STM overhead will hurt you.  I would be more inclined to serialize access to the heap to one thread at a time using locks / [MVars](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html).

I know [Data.Vector.Mutable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.7/doc/html/Data-Vector-Mutable.html) is a popular mutable array library.  Others will be more informed than I in recommending a good mutable array library for your purposes.

Comment: thanks. there is unclear thing for me. Why STM approach worse then MVars in my case. I look for STM as high level abstraction for standard concurrency locks.  Could you explain or get link to explanation why it is.

Comment: Here is the standard haskell STM paper: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/stm/stm.pdf .  STM does not check locks: instead it runs the code "provisionally", and right before the transaction ends it sees if anyone has changed any of the data that could have caused the transaction to go differently.  If not, it commits the variables to shared memory; if so, it aborts and tries the transaction again.  Because all heap transactions mutate the root, if two go at the same time one of them *must* retry.  So the performance can be no better than locks (and probably worse)

Comment: STM is a good choice if your transactions modify TVars *sparsely*; i.e. transactions that go at the same time are not that likely to depend on the same variables.

Answer (score 0):

Them moment you start to think in terms of "mutable memory area" and "operations that modify this memory area", you are going out of the boundaries of Pure FP languages like Haskell and stuff which goes out of this boundary will require some special techniques in haskell like Monads. In your case of Mutable data structure you are crossing the fundamental boundary which I am not sure if even a Monad can help you to cross (a Monad may help you to simulate it like a mutable data structure ex: state monad - but that wont be what you are looking for as you want it to be "mutable" and not just a simulation.

Comment: Monads have nothing to do with mutability. They're just an API idiom commonly used for safe access to mutable data (among other things). Primitive operations allowing actual mutability are provided by the runtime system and otherwise there's nothing special about them.